# How can I make an HTTP POST request in F#?

Tags: http, f#, http-post

The following code sends a GET request.  This is making me crazy.

```
let postDocRaw (url:string) (data: string) : string =
      let data' : byte[] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

      let request = WebRequest.Create(url)
      request.Method        <- "POST"
      request.ContentType   <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      request.ContentLength <- (int64) data'.Length

      use wstream = request.GetRequestStream() 
      wstream.Write(data',0, (data'.Length))
      wstream.Flush()
      wstream.Close()
(*
      use writer = new StreamWriter (wstream) 
      writer.Write(data')
      writer.Flush()
      writer.Close()
*)

      let response  = request.GetResponse()
      use reader     = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
      let output = reader.ReadToEnd()

      reader.Close()
      response.Close()
      request.Abort()

      output
```

At the moment I'm not sure that anyone has ever used F# to send an HTTP POST.  Has anyone seen documentation about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me. For example (`posttestserver.com` does really exist):

```
printfn "response: %A" (postDocRaw "http://posttestserver.com/post.php" "hello=data")
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Result:

```
response: "
Successfully dumped 1 post variables.Post body was 0 chars long.
"
```

Maybe you are using it in a different way?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't mean this as a trick question.  I'm not sure I understand what was going wrong, but I've gotten things working by changing the way I call it...   Thank you!

Comment: how can you set the Accept header in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

I found one MSDN article about [Request-Response Testing With F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942848.aspx)