# http client post async in c#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, httpclient, c#-to-f#

I've looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454157/how-can-i-make-an-http-post-request-in-f) to do a post request in F# but I'm wondering how to do the same using an async post request

```
type Authentication = 
    new() = {}
    member this.RequestToken() =
        use client = new HttpClient()
        client.PostAsync "http://example.com"

        printfn "requestToken"
```

**Edit**

comparable C# code as per request in the comments.

```
var body = "some data";

using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseProxy = false })) {

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com", new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"));
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you getting an error with your code? What error? Or does the code produce results different from what's expected? How are they different? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I need a jump start actually, I'm coming from c# but not sure how to proceed with the above code, also I couldn't set the headers for accept, `request.Headers.Set "Accept" "application/json;charset=UTF-8"`, can you provide a full example?

Comment: If you seek a C#-to-F# translation, please provide the C# code in question. Then somebody will be able to translate for you.

Comment: I was hesitant since one time someone commented, SO is not a translation service, edited my question.

Comment: As long as you made an effort to do it yourself, asking for help is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For F# asynchronous code, you need to use an `async` computation expression and `Async.AwaitTask` to convert from C#'s `Task<_>` type to F#'s `Async<_>`. I suggest you look up some documentation about F# async workflows.

```
type Authentication = 
    new() = {}
    member this.RequestToken() =
        async {
            use client = new HttpClient()
            let! response = client.PostAsync "http://example.com" |> Async.AwaitTask
            let! content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            return content
        }
```

Comment: thanks, can you help with how to specify headers for content-type and accept?

Comment: it has an error, it says `PostAsync doesn't take 1 argument(s), An overload was found taking two arguments`